# mock implementation for feign client would not be autowire

Tags: mocking, spring-test-mvc, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

i want to test my spring project. i need to mock a feign client in a test class but normal implementation would be autowired instead of mock implementation. here is top of my codes. plz help.

```
@Profile("test")
@Primary
@Component
public class PushDevClientMock implements PushDevClient {

//apiKey is needed for comminucating with GCM
private static final String apiKey = "AIzaSyC7nH1yMgfGnEHbOHCgAeOrspMReaj0hCg";
@Override
public ResponseEntity<PushInstanceResponse> getPushInstance(@PathVariable("instanceId") String instanceId) {

    ResponseEntity<PushInstanceResponse> response;
    if (instanceId == null) {
        response = new ResponseEntity<PushInstanceResponse>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    else {
        PushInstanceResponse body = new PushInstanceResponse();
        body.setApiKey(apiKey);
        response = new ResponseEntity<PushInstanceResponse>(body,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    return response;
}
```

}

here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port:0", "spring.profiles.active:test"})
public class RegistrationControllerTest {

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
TokenRepository tokenRepository;

private static MockMvc mockMvc;
private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//    token and sender id are required for communicating with google
private static String senderId = "553921561995";
private static String token =
"ecdNq6_jeTM:APA91bEgWsJeIS5cXFwWrj_83EKeLWRFf1" +
        "-     lNQGXA1uWdzrfHLpd7fAY7ur6Pplc4TQuKmEDiSUhUBhDdQLwG2a_fxdgoGbDrKNLjPm2E7JOMJFjk65jtFGHrjJ39NkgABtfn6MDVUCQ";

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    tokenRepository.deleteAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `RegistrationControllerTest` with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

Answer (score 0):

1. I removed `@EnableFeignClients`  from Application.java
2. Add empty configuration class like this :

   ```
   @Configuration
   @Profile("!test")
   @EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "ir.pegahtech.backtory.push_api") //this is my project root
   public class FeignClientConfiguration {
   }
   ```

Now everything works fine